# Python подтягивание названий предметов по id из второго массива

Tags: python, массивы, list, dict

Первый массив хранит ид предмета и количество:

```
{'items': [
 {'item_id': 1, 'count': 127}, 
 {'item_id': 2, 'count': 123}
]}
```

Второй массив хранит названия для этих идов предметов:

```
[
 {'item_id': 1, 'title': 'Название предмета 1'}, 
 {'item_id': 2, 'title': 'Название предмета 2'}
]
```

Как я могу "соединить" эти данные и получить массив следующего вида? :

```
[
 {'title': 'Название предмета 1', 'count': 127, 'item_id': 1}, 
 {'title': 'Название предмета 2', 'count': 123, 'item_id': 2}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, вам проще сразу работать с дейтафреймами pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'items': [
    {'item_id': 1, 'count': 127}, 
    {'item_id': 2, 'count': 123},
    {'item_id': 8, 'count':None}
    ]}

b = [
    {'item_id': 1, 'title': 'Название предмета 1'}, 
    {'item_id': 2, 'title': 'Название предмета 2'},
    {'item_id': 5, 'title': 'Название предмета 5'}   
    ]

dfa = pd.DataFrame(a['items'],columns=['item_id', 'count'])
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['item_id', 'title'])
res = dfa.merge(dfb,on="item_id", how='outer')
```

Получаем `dataframe` `res`, при этом количество элементов в исходных списках может быть разным, могут отсутствовать значения, и не нужно городить многоэтажные циклы:

```
   item_id  count                title
0        1  127.0  Название предмета 1
1        2  123.0  Название предмета 2
2        8    NaN                  NaN
3        5    NaN  Название предмета 5
```

Answer (score 1):

В каждом массиве одинаковое количество элементов и одинаковые id? Если да, то это может Вам помочь:

```py
raw_a = {'items': [
    {'item_id': 1, 'count': 127},
    {'item_id': 2, 'count': 123}
]}

a = raw_a['items']
b = [
    {'item_id': 1, 'title': 'Название предмета 1'},
    {'item_id': 2, 'title': 'Название предмета 2'}
]

c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    x = {**a[i], **b[i]}
    c.append(x)

print(c)
```

*stdout:*

```py
[{'item_id': 1, 'count': 127, 'title': 'Название предмета 1'}, {'item_id': 2, 'count': 123, 'title': 'Название предмета 2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Работает в том числе при разном количестве и несоответствии порядка элементов в первом и втором массивах.

```
a = {'items': [{'item_id': 1, 'count': 127},
               {'item_id': 2, 'count': 123},
               {'item_id': 3, 'count': 0}]
     }

# item неупорядочены.
b = [{'item_id': 1, 'title': 'Название предмета 1'},
     {'item_id': 2, 'title': 'Название предмета 2'},
     {'item_id': 4, 'title': 'Название предмета 4'},
     {'item_id': 3, 'title': 'Название предмета 3'}]

a_and_b = []

for item_a in a['items']:
    for item_b in b:
        if item_a['item_id'] == item_b['item_id']:
            a_and_b.append(
                {'title': item_b['title'],
                 'count': item_a['count'],
                 'item_id': item_a['item_id']}
            )

print(a_and_b)
```

*stdout*:

```
[{'title': 'Название предмета 1', 'count': 127, 'item_id': 1}, {'title': 'Название предмета 2', 'count': 123, 'item_id': 2}, {'title': 'Название предмета 3', 'count': 0, 'item_id': 3}]
```